# Force WPF ListView to update DesiredSize before being rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, layout

I have a WPF ListView with "Auto" column widths. After rendering, the column widths correctly match content, that is ok.

I need to determine the correct (rendered) DesiredSize of the ListView right after assigning to ItemsSource, prior to rendering.

The problem is that calling Measure() breaks the Auto width behavior - it resizes the columns to match *header* content:

```
listView.ItemsSource = myCollection;
// now listView.DesiredSize is 0
listView.Measure(new Size(2000, 2000));  // this breaks "Auto" widths
```

The only hack that comes to my mind is adding spaces to headers manually.